# How to extract numbers from csv file into variable

Tags: python

I want to make a highscore in a game on python - todo this i've realised I have to use an external file. I want it to extract the numbers located in the file and save them as a variable. It will then compare it to the users score and if it's bigger it will write the new high score to the file

I've been googling for days with no luck.

```
while theo >= 0 and theo <=9:
    theo = theo + 1
    x = (random.randint(0, 12))
    y = (random.randint(0, 12))
    print("Your sum is: " ,y,"x ",x)
    answer = input("What is the answer?: ")
    while len(answer) == 0:
        answer = input("What is the answer?: ")
        an = (x*y)             
    if int(answer) == (an):
        print("Well done - you were correct ")
        score = score + 1

    elif int(answer) != (an): 
        print("Sorry, you were wrong. The correct answer was " ,an)
    if theo == (10):
        print("The quiz has finished. your score is ",score)
        again = input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N)")
        gamesplayed = gamesplayed + 1
        if again == ("Y") or again == ("y"):
                theo = 0
                timesplayed = timesplayed + 1
        elif again!=("y") or again!=("Y"):
            print("well done your final score was ",score," you played ",timesplayed," times")
```

I want it to do above

Comment: Attach the example data of your file

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use [dataclass CSV](https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-csv/) whenever I work with CSV files. You just need to type the column as integer (you do that by typing dataclass attribute as `int`)

It is a nice clean way to convert CSV rows to python objects. The only restriction is that you need to use python3.7 or higher.